# Monitoring a log file for systemd service startup

Tags: docker, service, systemd

I'm trying to run a Docker container as a service.  It's a clustered service across several different servers, and it can take a few seconds to connect.  The container will occasionally get stuck in a failure loop without actually exiting the container.  So systemd mistakenly reports the startup as successful.  I'm trying to monitor the process with these things in my unit file:

```
TimeoutStartSec=60
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop %n
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm %n
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull my_container
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name %n my_container
ExecStartPost=until [ /usr/bin/docker logs %n 2>&1 | grep -m 1 \"All services up and running.\" ]; do sleep 1; done
```

When I run `systemctl start myservice`, it takes few seconds to start (seemingly because of the `docker pull`), but returns a success relatively quickly.

However, if I manually run `docker logs -f myservice.service`, I see that the service doesn't log "All services are up and running" for a few more seconds.

I've looked at https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker, but I'm wary about a repo that hasn't been updated in over a year (seems Darren is busy with Rancher).

So, my question: Why doesn't my ExecStartPost work?  Is there a better way to launch containers as a service directly with systemd?

Comment: Do you really need systemd? The Docker daemon will keep processes running.... The "run" command has a restart policy option: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/restart-policies---restart

Comment: I need to run multiple interdependent services in production, so I want a clean(ish) way to manage them.  I'm not sure how I'd use `docker run` directly.  rc.local?  manual?

Comment: The Docker daemon is process manager in its own right. When you run a container with the "-d" and "--restart=always" options it'll run in the background and be automatically restarted upon failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get this to work, and the solution is a bit of a facepalm.  What I was trying to do was fine, I just needed the full path to grep and sleep.

```
TimeoutStartSec=60
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop %n
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm %n
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull my_container
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name %n my_container
ExecStartPost=until [ /usr/bin/docker logs %n 2>&1 | /bin/grep -m 1 \"String that indicates my service is up successfully\" ]; do /bin/sleep 1; done
```

I've tested it out a bit, and it seems to work pretty well.